# How get data with angular and send it with node.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm changing my node.js application, i was using EJS template engine and now i want use angular.

For this i already install angular and is working good, but now i want get my data, and for this i'm using the $http service:

```
(function($) {
  app.controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.data;

    $http.get('/data').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;

      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;

      });

  }]);

}(jQuery));
```

And i'm sending the data in the backend:

```
  restAPI.GET(options).then(function (result) {
    res.render('data/index.html', {
      event: result,
    });
  }).then(undefined, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

But its returning the HTML from the same page that i'm using the controller. What am i doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.data = data;
```

The config variable is supposed to return this:

> config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate
>   the request.

Also, you can look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to see what all variables on the success function mean.

Comment: sorry Mário, i copy wrong, i'm using data, and is returning the HTML, not the real data :B.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to supply render with a callback function. as in:

```
res.render('data/index', {event: result}, function(error, theHtml) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send(theHtml);
})
```

Comment: Oops, I had theHtml being logged instead of actually sent!